# Socket Architecture Between Multiple Activities

Tags: android, sockets

I am starting to write an application which uses a socket to communicate with another device. I am currently trying to design the architecture of the application. It will have multiple activities. My question is if I have a single socket instance that gets passed between activities, or is declared in a class which extends Application, how do I know when to close it unless I open and close it in each activity? - Although this would work I am unsure if it is the 'cleanest' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find another good way of doing what you want. I would create the object inside the application class or as a singleton. And maybe create a BaseActivity class which will get the reference in onCreate and release it on onDestroy. This class you would extend in every activity you want to use your object in.

I would also track the references inside the Singleton class that defines your "socket", meaning have a counter which is incremented on each get and decremented on each release call. when the counter gets to 0 you can close the socket or better post a runnable which will close it after a specific time if no new activities "get" the reference again.

I have done something similar in my library for handling runnable.

Check it out here:
[BaseObservableThreadPoolService](https://github.com/darko1002001/android-rest-client/blob/master/android-rest-lib/src/main/java/com/dg/libs/rest/services/BaseObservableThreadPoolServiceService.java) |
[ThreadCountObserver](https://github.com/darko1002001/android-rest-client/blob/master/android-rest-lib/src/main/java/com/dg/libs/rest/services/ThreadCountObserver.java)